# jquery data tabel server side pagination with spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

The below code is used to generate table and populate data in server side pagination. But i'm getting null pointer exception. Data table not sending data to spring controller.
**table declarations**

```
  var publicArticleTbl = $('#tblArticles').dataTable({
                                    "aoColumns" : [null],
                                    "bProcessing" : true,
                                    "bServerSide" : true,
                                    "bLenthChange" : false,
                                    "iDisplayLength" : 10,
                                    "iDisplayStart":  1,
                                    "bFilter": false,
                                    "bInfo": false,
                        });
```

**spring controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllArticles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllArticles(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int currPos = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"));
        int pageSize = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayLength"));
        List<Article> articles = articleService.getAllArtilcles(currPos, pageSize);
        int totalRecords = articleService.getAllArticleCount();

        ArticleDataTableObject dataTableObject = new ArticleDataTableObject();

        dataTableObject.setiTotalDisplayRecords(totalRecords);
        // the total data in db for datatables to calculate page no.
        dataTableObject.setiTotalRecords(totalRecords);
        dataTableObject.setsEcho(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sEcho")));
        dataTableObject.setAaData(articles);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(dataTableObject);
        return json;
    }
```

`int currPos = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"));
        int pageSize = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayLength"));`

The above line getting null pointer exception. Why js table not sending `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength`

Comment: Where are you passing iDisplayStart ? You need to post the code

Comment: It is inside table declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Pete i know i'm getting null pointer exception , my question is why the field is null even if i passed from client side.